# Geographic text recognition

Tags: image-processing, geography, machine-learning, ocr

I would like to process an image from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2012) to get the structured data out

[image: electoral map]

Like so

```
<| "New York" -> 28, ... |>
```

Not sure where to start.

Comment: You can start with `CountryData`. guess projection and highlight image for each state, text recognize on what is left. Mask whole country and try to text recognize rest.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and Kuba's approach is very promising as well, but if all you need is the data, then you could extract it more easily from a tabular form from e.g. [here](http://psephos.adam-carr.net/countries/u/usa/pres/usa2008.txt). Alternatively, [an equivalent map](http://psephos.adam-carr.net/countries/u/usa/mapspres/2008.GIF) [from Adam Carr's site](http://psephos.adam-carr.net/) have a zoomed in version for New England that may make it easier to extract those states' values.

Comment: @MarcoB the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2012#Votes_by_electoral_college) has that data, you just have to scroll a little bit. But, I think your version of the data is far easier to parse.

Comment: I have joined two others in voting to close this as **too broad**.  As always if someone has an answer they wish to post please **flag** the post for moderator attention and let me know.  M.R. I hope this can be narrowed somewhat as I find it interesting.